# How to make Transaction work as expected in DB Browser for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am testing a set of migration code on existing DB.

I have try to execute multiple SQLite statements within a transaction, in DB Browser for SQLite.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE `plain_note_new` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `label` TEXT, `title` TEXT, `body` TEXT, `type` INTEGER NOT NULL, `color_index` INTEGER NOT NULL, `custom_color` INTEGER NOT NULL, `locked` INTEGER NOT NULL, `pinned` INTEGER NOT NULL, `checked` INTEGER NOT NULL, `archived` INTEGER NOT NULL, `trashed` INTEGER NOT NULL, `sticky` INTEGER NOT NULL, `sticky_icon` INTEGER NOT NULL, `order` INTEGER NOT NULL, `searched_string` TEXT, `reminder_type` INTEGER NOT NULL, `reminder_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `reminder_repeat` INTEGER NOT NULL, `reminder_end_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `reminder_active_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `reminder_last_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `reminder_repeat_frequency` INTEGER NOT NULL, `reminder_day_of_week_bitwise` INTEGER NOT NULL, `created_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `modified_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `trashed_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `synced_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `uuid` TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `plain_note_new` SELECT `id`, `label`, `title`, `body`, `type`, `color_index`, `custom_color`, `locked`, `pinned`, `checked`, `archived`, `trashed`, `sticky`, `sticky_icon`, `order`, `searched_string`, `reminder_type`, `reminder_timestamp`, `reminder_repeat`, `reminder_end_timestamp`, `reminder_active_timestamp`, `reminder_last_timestamp`, `reminder_repeat_frequency`, `reminder_day_of_week_bitwise`, `created_timestamp`, `modified_timestamp`, `trashed_timestamp`, `synced_timestamp`, `uuid` FROM `plain_note`;
DROP INDEX `index_plain_note_archived`;
DROP INDEX `index_plain_note_label`;
DROP INDEX `index_plain_note_sticky`;
DROP INDEX `index_plain_note_trashed`;
DROP INDEX `index_plain_note_uuid`;
DROP TABLE `plain_note`;

BAD COMMAND;

ALTER TABLE `plain_note_new` RENAME TO `plain_note`;
CREATE INDEX `index_plain_note_archived` ON `plain_note` (`archived`);
CREATE INDEX `index_plain_note_label` ON `plain_note` (`label`);
CREATE INDEX `index_plain_note_sticky` ON `plain_note` (`sticky`);
CREATE INDEX `index_plain_note_trashed` ON `plain_note` (`trashed`);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_plain_note_uuid` ON `plain_note` (`uuid`);
CREATE INDEX `index_plain_note_uuid_synced_timestamp` ON `plain_note` (`uuid`, `synced_timestamp`);
COMMIT;
```

I expect due to `BAD COMMAND`, the transaction will not be committed. Hence, both indices and table will not be dropped.

However, when I click on the Play button

[image]

The tables and indices are still being dropped.

Even I start all over again, and tried by removing `COMMIT` from the UI, the outcome is still not desired (plain_note table is removed, and multiple indices are removed)

I expect since we do not end the transaction, actual table and indices removal should not happen. May I know, why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

DB Browser for sqlite manages transactions as per [this doc](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Transactions). Observe that even if a COMMIT; is issued, the `Write Changes` and `Revert Changes` buttons are still active. I expect that DB4S [discards transaction commands](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/1859#issuecomment-494095823) (begin, commit, rollback) to maintain the integrity of the Write and Revert Changes buttons.